# Can I nondimensionalize the model only when the total population is constant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I have the following ODE [model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFZNs.png) that I [nondimensionalized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8ulv.png) and I received feedback on it saying that "**Author scale the population of human by divide each class with the total of
human population (N_h). Author can do this only if the total of human population is
constant. As equation (10) shows, there exist a death rate due to diseases in their
model. Hence, all calculation which use a scale of the human population should be
recalculated.**" I am wondering if the reviewer wants me to not do nondimensionalization and use equations 1-9 to do further analysis instead of using equations 15-19. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is a grave error. You either use constants in the non-dimensionalisation, which means that $N_h$ and $N_v$ reduce to non-constant dependent variables $n_h$ and $n_v$. Or you need to apply the quotient rule
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{X}{N}=\frac{\dot X}{N}-\frac{\dot N}{N}·\frac{X}{N},
$$
You can not leave out the second term, you would get a different dynamic.

Comment: Can I take b_h=mu_h so that N_h becomes constant and then use nondimensionalization?

Comment: It would only become constant if the derivative were zero. But that does only happen in the non-interesting case where $I=0$ for all times and variants.